# Angular directive and controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive and a controller. The directive as fallows:

```
calcP.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        replace: true, 
        transclude: true, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            **scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
                delete $sope.types.individual;**
            };
        },
        template: "..."
    };
});
```

My controller:

```
    calcP.controller('calcPCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, emailSenderEndpoint) {

$scope.getVariantDomovoy = function () {
        $scope.types.domovoy = $scope.variants.domovoy;
    };
    $scope.getVariantIndividual = function () {
        $scope.types.individual = $scope.variants.individual;
    };

    ...
    $scope.modalShown = false;
        $scope.toggleModal = function() {
            $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
        };

    });
```

My template:

```
template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
```

I'd like to delete some $scope by adding it to a function. But the browser shows the error that it can't find the variable $scope.types.individual.

I just try to learnAangularJS by myself and still have some problems.

Comment: `delete $sope.types.individual;` ?? or `delete $scope.types.individual;`??

Comment: As I understand correctly your `types` is on your controller? So you can do `delete $scope.$parent.types.individual;` But it seems you're trying to achieve something and use a non-angular way of doing so

Comment: @DilumN Yes, $scope, sorry .. but I still have the same error

Comment: And where does `$scope` come from?

Comment: @zeroflagL $scope is in my controller.

Comment: @devqon Yes, you are right, $scope is in my controller

Comment: Saying that there is an error is not enough. If there is a one, please, show it entirely.

Comment: from your controller? wich one? can you publish your controller code and the template of your directive too please?

Comment: @Sphinx117 here they are

Comment: So look to @DilumN  answer! he 's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change a value of your controller from a directive, first you have to pass that variable to the directive with two way binding. Then you can change that value as below.

```
calcP.directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '=',
            types: '='
        },
        replace: true, 
        transclude: true, 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dialogStyle = {};
            if (attrs.width)
                scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
            if (attrs.height)
                scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
            **scope.hideModal = function() {
                scope.show = false;
                scope.types.individual = "";**
            };
        },
        template: "..."
    };
});
```

Make sure you are passing your `$scope.types` from the controller to the directive. Same as you pass `show` parameter

May be like this,

```
<model-dialog show="show" types="types"></model-dialog>
```

Comment: I have added my template to the original post. I have the whole application inside <model-dialog>

Comment: Can you put your html code where you include `<model-dialog>`

Comment: Sorry, I have found my mistake. Your answer helped me. Thank you very much.